# Spring Boot - MongoDB integration test database config change

Tags: spring, mongodb, integration-testing

**MongoDBConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages="......persistence.repositories")
public class MongoDBConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private String port;
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create("mongodb://" + host + ":" + port);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      username:
      password:
      database: spring-mongodb-demo
```

With the above configurations, spring app using mongo database as per defined in yml - **spring-mongodb-demo**.

One of my integration test beings like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;
```

When I run an integration tests it uses the database named - **test**.

I want the integration tests to use the database  - **spring-mongodb-demo** as per defined in yml file or setting a different database as my preference.

I have tried by making a new profile named **application-test.yml** and set **@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")** in test class.

I have found lots of thread in this regard, nothing worked.

Comment: can you try TestPropertySource? For usage check https://github.com/sonus21/rqueue/blob/36bb806681a51f80588e028cf12d0730612a3bf1/rqueue-spring/src/test/java/com/github/sonus21/rqueue/spring/tests/integration/SpringMetricTest.java#L34

Comment: @sonus21 Thanks for pointing out `@TestPropertySource` and inline property change worked as your example. However, setting new properties file for test classes is a better option like this - `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")` . The location of the file is - `test/resources/test.properties`